# Extract data from json response in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, postman-testcase

How do I extract `personReference` from the `json` response in postman tool? I just wanted to extract the `personReference` & parameterized it in next level requests:

```json
{
    "result": "https://hi.helloworld.com/UAT?personReference=CD6alG%2Fwl0CxX9ARraBexg%3D%3D&commMethodReference=C3%2BQqN7vBUhGbb8hytvSTA%3D%3D&
code=s6wodIXv7Pd5XPE4Sa7WzGT4BhZgi%2FL67hDQ7sfLG2A%3D",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

personReference is not part of the json response. It is simply part of the String value of result. Ideally you can set global variable by

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("variable_key", jsonData.result);
```

It will set the whole value of result in Global Variable "variable_key".
You can set it as environment variable by

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("variable_key", jsonData.result);\
```

For your special case you need to write few logic in Javascript like(I did not try this, if it does not work please refer to more robust ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)):

```
var url = new URL(result);
var c = url.searchParams.get("personReference ");
```